# Slow loading of Turf.JS Hexbin and Count with Mapbox Studio Baselayer

Tags: mapbox, turfjs

I've been having difficulty with slow loading of a project I've been looking to fork that was on the Mapbox blog ([link here](http://bl.ocks.org/wboykinm/29ef7eda9e28932353fd)).

I've substituted in my own mapbox key, redefined the bbox to focus on the Ukraine, and re-centered the map on my own mapbox studio baselayer. However, the page loads painfully slowly when I render it in MAMP locally on my computer or when it's uploaded to an S3 bucket.

Not sure what I've done wrong or what I could change to make it render quicker like in the bl.ocks.org example.

Link here for my version of the above project: https://s3.amazonaws.com/conflict.donbass/ukraine2.html

Comment: Can you post a link to your data? I think it has something to do with your data.

Answer (score 0):

I think has something to do with the bbox size, try setting it to [33, 44.2, 40.6, 50.3]

Comment: This could be a comment.